# ClassCastException when using formatDate

Tags: java, spring, classcastexception

I'm having trouble trying to figure out why my formatDate is not working correctly.  Here is my code:

Java

```
@DateTimeFormat(style = "SS")
@Column(name="my_date")
private Date myDate;

public Date getMyDate() {
    return this.myDate;
}
public void setMyDate(Date myDate) {
    this.myDate = myDate;
}
```

JSP - portion of the code that uses the fmt:formatDate code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:forEach var="foo" items="${fooList}" varStatus="i">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${i.index+1}</td>                           
                            <td>${foo.id}</td>
                            <td>${foo.name}</td>
                            <td><fmt:formatDate value="${foo.myDate}" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/></td>
                        </tr>
```

Web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Here is a modified version of the controller, all parts dealing with the date are shown here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
public String list(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model uiModel) {      
    List<foo> fooList = createList(fooList);

    uiModel.addAttribute("fooList", fooList);   

    return VIEW_OBJECT;
}
```

When running my application I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JstlUtils$SpringLocalizationContext incompatible with java.lang.String
```

***Error only shows when formateDate code is in there, otherwise all EL evaluate fine.

Anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: Does all your other EL evaluate correctly?

Comment: try uri = http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt_rt

Comment: @Dave everything seems to be evaluating correctly.  The only time the page throws this error is when the format code is in there.

Comment: @RanRag I tried that and it says that it can't find the tag library descriptor..

Comment: How is the data being exposed to the JSP?

Comment: @Dave I updated the code to give you a better feel of what may be going on.

Comment: I'm concerned about the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation also being on the field--is Spring already converting the field inside the JSP because of that?

Comment: @Dave I had thought that maybe that was the reason I was having issues, but when I remove that line of code, the behavior is still the same so it's almost like it's doing nothing. My date is being displayed as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and with the SS style it should be M/d/yy HH:mm

Comment: Wait, how is it being displayed?

Comment: @Dave it displays as 2010-06-03 00:00:00.0

Comment: No, I mean *how* is it being displayed? You said the `fmt` tag was throwing.

Comment: @Dave I guess I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.. when using the fmt tag I get the error up above.  I think I may try and figure out why the spring annotation isn't working because I believe that i can just say @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy") and it _should_ work.  Then I can get rid of the fmt stuff that I can't seem to fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution as to why my fmt tag was not working.  I needed to change my dependency from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

To:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I could not change the dependencies, so my solution was to use a scriptlet. I does not solve the fmt:formatDate, but it can be used as workarround:

```
<c:forEach var="foo" items="${fooList}" varStatus="i">
<tr>
<td>${i.index+1}</td>
<td>${foo.id}</td>
<td>${foo.name}</td>

<%--Scriptlet alternative: %>
<c:set var="fooMyDate" value="${foo.myDate}" scope="request"/>
<%
    Object myDate = request.getAttribute("fooMyDate");
    java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
%>
<td><%= df.format(myDate)%></td>

</tr>
```